# Convert a line (containing strings and integers) into integer array in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

I have a line which has space separated strings:

```
line="hello 3] 5c 100 memory"
```

I want to split this string into an integer array, so that the following:

```
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}
```

> Outputs 3 5 100

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 3):

With Bash's [Parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
line="hello 3] 5c 100 memory"
arr=(${line//[^0-9 ]/})        # replace everything but 0-9 and space with nothing
declare -p arr
```

Output:

```
declare -a arr='([0]="3" [1]="5" [2]="100")'
```